# Extending on a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: plugins

I heard you can make a new plugin based off of another one to extend on it. All I want to do is add a few bits of code without editing or deleting anything else. Is my scenario possible (making a new plugin that only extends on the original so not to make edits to the original?

The actual plugin code. The main file when first going into the plugins folder is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
(
author etc is here)
if ( ! class_exists( 'Inventor' ) ) {

/**
 * Class Inventor
 *
 * @class Inventor
 * @package Inventor
 * @author Pragmatic Mates
 */
final class Inventor {
    const DOMAIN = 'inventor';

    /**
     * Initialize plugin
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->constants();
        $this->libraries();
        $this->includes();
        Inventor_Utilities::load_plugin_textdomain( self::DOMAIN, __FILE__ );

        if ( 'SESSION' == apply_filters( 'inventor_visitor_data_destination', INVENTOR_DEFAULT_VISITOR_DATA_STORAGE ) ) {
            add_action( 'init', array(__CLASS__, 'start_session'), 1 );
        }

        add_action( 'activated_plugin', array( __CLASS__, 'plugin_order' ) );
        add_action( 'tgmpa_register', array( __CLASS__, 'register_plugins' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Defines constants
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function constants() {
        define( 'INVENTOR_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
        define( 'INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX', 'listing_' );
        define( 'INVENTOR_LISTING_CATEGORY_PREFIX', 'listing_category_' );
        define( 'INVENTOR_TRANSACTION_PREFIX', 'transaction_' );
        define( 'INVENTOR_REPORT_PREFIX', 'report_' );
        define( 'INVENTOR_USER_PREFIX', 'user_' );
        define( 'INVENTOR_MAIL_ACTION_REPORTED_LISTING', 'REPORTED_LISTING' );
        define( 'INVENTOR_DEFAULT_VISITOR_DATA_STORAGE', 'COOKIE' );

        define( 'INVENTOR_API_ENDPOINT', 'http://inventorwp.com/api/v1/' );
        define( 'INVENTOR_API_VERIFY_URL', INVENTOR_API_ENDPOINT . 'verify/' );
    }

    /**
     * Include classes
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function includes() {
        if ( apply_filters( 'inventor_database_session_handler_enabled', false ) ) {
            require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-session-handler.php';
        }
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-scripts.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-template-loader.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-metaboxes.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-post-types.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-field-types.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-taxonomies.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-price.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-widgets.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-filter.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-visitor.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-utilities.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-query.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-shortcodes.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-social.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-billing.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-wire-transfer.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-reports.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-customizations.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/class-inventor-migrations.php';

        // Admin
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/admin/class-inventor-admin-menu.php';
            require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/admin/class-inventor-admin-notices.php';
            require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/admin/class-inventor-admin-updates.php';
            require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'includes/admin/class-inventor-admin-dashboard.php';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads third party libraries
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public static function libraries() {
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'libraries/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'libraries/cmb_field_map/cmb-field-map.php';
        require_once INVENTOR_DIR . 'libraries/cmb_field_street_view/cmb-field-street-view.php';
    }

    /**
     * Install plugins
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public static function register_plugins() {
        $plugins = array(
            array(
                'name'                  => 'CMB2',
                'slug'                  => 'cmb2',
                'is_automatic'          => true,
                'required'              => true,
                'version'               => '2.2.2.1'
            ),
        );

        tgmpa( $plugins );
    }

    /**
     * Start session
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public static function start_session() {
        session_id() or session_start();
    }

    /**
     * Loads this plugin first
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public static function plugin_order() {
        $wp_path_to_this_file = preg_replace( '/(.*)plugins\/(.*)$/', WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/$2', __FILE__ );
        $this_plugin = plugin_basename( trim( $wp_path_to_this_file ) );
        $active_plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' );

        $this_plugin_key = array_search( $this_plugin, $active_plugins );

        if ( $this_plugin_key ) {
            array_splice( $active_plugins, $this_plugin_key, 1 );
            array_unshift( $active_plugins, $this_plugin );
            update_option( 'active_plugins', $active_plugins );
        }
    }
}

new Inventor();
```

}

There is a second file as well within this plugin. Here is a snippit at the parts I want to addon to a row.php file

```
<?php $featured = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX . 'featured', true ); ?>
<?php $reduced = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX . 'reduced', true ); ?>

A bunch of code is here

<div class="listing-row <?php if ( $featured ) : ?>featured<?php endif; ?>">
<div class="listing-row-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_attr( $image ); ?>');">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="listing-row-image-link"></a>

    <div class="listing-row-actions">
        <?php do_action( 'inventor_listing_actions', get_the_ID(), 'row' ); ?>
    </div><!-- /.listing-row-actions -->

    <?php if ( $featured ) : ?>
        <div class="listing-row-label-top listing-row-label-top-left"><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Featured', 'inventor' ); ?></div><!-- /.listing-row-label-top-left -->
    <?php endif; ?>

     <?php if ( $pink ) : ?>
        <div class="listing-row-label-top listing-row-label-top-left"><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Pink', 'inventor' ); ?></div><!-- /.listing-row-label-top-left -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $reduced ) : ?>
        <div class="listing-row-label-top listing-row-label-top-right"><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Reduced', 'inventor' ); ?></div><!-- /.listing-row-label-top-right -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $listing_type_name = Inventor_Post_Types::get_listing_type_name(); ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $listing_type_name ) ) : ?>
        <div class="listing-row-label-bottom"><?php echo wp_kses( $listing_type_name, wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) ); ?></div><!-- /.listing-row-label-bottom -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- /.listing-row-image -->
```

Now then, what i want to do is in a new plugin to extend off of this is add in these 2 parts to my own plugin file.

```
    <?php $gold = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX . 'gold', true ); ?>
```

at the top. and then

```
    <?php if ( $gold ) : ?>
        <div class="listing-row-label-top listing-row-label-top-left"><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Gold', 'inventor' ); ?></div><!-- /.listing-row-label-top-left -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

which will be placed in the div class="listing-row-actions">' section

So is there a way to make a plugin extension kind of thing so I do not make edits to the original plugin

Comment: If the original author of the plugin left you such the opportunity, then you are lucky! Remember, any changes you make to the plugin files directly will be overwritten at the next plugin update.

Comment: What is the specific plugin and is there any documentation for it? Where is the `row.php` file and how is it called from within the plugin files? With regard to where you want to pull in your custom code, I'm guessing you actually mean **below** the `<the div class="listing-row-actions">` section and not **in** it..? Please confirm...

Comment: The plugin is 'inventor'. the row.php file is in another folder within the plugin.

And yes, it would be below that line of code. It is not replacing it or anything, just going below it. (it will be a new to go with the reduced, pink, and featured which has similar code.